# unknown packages in requirements.txt - andas, cipy

Tags: python, requirements.txt

I am trying to create a requirements.txt file to list out the dependencies needed in my project. using

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```

which compiles all my dependencies and

```
pipreqs /path/to/my/project/
```

creates a list with my project dependencies. However, I see some weird dependencies that are named similarly to the usual packages:

```
tensorflow==2.3.0
~andas==1.0.5
matplotlib==3.2.2
~cipy==1.4.1
numpy==1.18.5
pandas==1.2.4
scipy==1.6.3
```

i.e. andas and cipy?

i can't find what these packages are and i cant import them in python. Is it safe to delete them from the requirements.txt? How do i uninstall these weird packages?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess it must be `pandas` and `scipy`

Comment: @bigbounty yes i thought so too but in my full requirements, pandas and scipy are already included?

Comment: Can you please [edit] to provide additional details? If `pip` genuinely thinks these packages are installed, where are the corresponding files, how are they named, and what do they contain?

Comment: Ase there any weird control characters in the output of `pip`? Many flabbergasting symptoms are because somebody used a Windows aditor and wrecked the line endings in a text file somewhere. (I know; friends don't let friends use Windows.)